# Is an equilateral triangle constructible in a Tarski plane?

Tags: lo.logic, mg.metric-geometry, model-theory, geometric-constructions

By a *Tarski space* I understand a mathematical structure $(X,\mathsf B,\equiv)$ consisting of set $X$, a *betweenness relation* $\mathsf B\subseteq X^3$ and a *congruence relation* ${\equiv}\subseteq X^2\times X^2$ satisfying all [Tarski's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms) except for the Euclid Axiom, the Axiom of Continuity, and the Dimension Axioms. In other words, Tarski spaces should satisfy seven Tarski's axioms: (1) Reflexivity of Congruence, (2) Identity of Congruence, (3) Transitivity of Congruence, (4) Identity of Betweenness, (5) Five Segments, (6) Segment Construction, (7) Inner Pasch Axiom. A Tarski space is called a *Tarski plane* if it has affine dimension 2.

As shown in the book of [Schwabhäuser, Szmielew, and Tarski](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-69418-9), a substantial portion of familiar (absolute) geometry holds in Tarski spaces of dimension $\ge 2$. In particular, one can construct midpoints and right triangles with given sides. By definition, a point $m$ is *the midpoint* between points $x$ and $y$ if $\mathsf Bxmy$ and $xm\equiv my$. Given three points $x,o,y$ of a Tarski space $X$, we write $\mathsf Rxoy$ and say that the angle $\angle xoy$ is *right* if $xy\equiv \dot xy$ where $\dot x$ is a unique point such that $o$ is the midpoint between $x$ and $\dot x$.

The geometric constructions in a Tarski space correspond to constructions with the help of a straightedge and a [divider](https://www.britannica.com/technology/divider-measurement-instrument) (the latter tool can be used to measure and transfer distances on lines, but not to draw circles).

**Problem 1.** Is an equilateral tringle constructible in a Tarski plane?

**Remark.** An equilateral triangle can be easily constructed in a Tarski space of dimension $\ge 3$: since we can construct perpendiculars to lines and planes in a Tarski space of dimension $\ge 3$, we can choose points $o,a,b,c$ such that $oa\equiv ob\equiv oc$ and $\mathsf Raob$, $\mathsf Raoc$ and $\mathsf Rboc$. Then the triangle $abc$ is equilateral.

In fact, we can mimic this construction also in dimension 2:

First, using a straightedge and a divider, construct points $a,o,b$ such that $ao\equiv ob$ and $\mathsf Raob$; then find the midpoint $m$ between the points $a$ and $b$. Construct a right triangle $mo\tilde c$ with sides $mo$ and $o\tilde c\equiv oa$. Finally take any point $c$ such that $\mathsf Rcma$ and $cm\equiv o\tilde c$.

[image: constructing an equilateral triangle]

**Problem 2.** Is the triangle $abc$ equilateral? Equivalently, can the congruence $ac\equiv ab$ be proved using only the seven axioms of a Tarski space?

This indeed can be done if the dimension of the Tarski space is $\ge 3$. This observation shows that Problems 1 and 2 are related to [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438323/does-every-tarski-plane-embed-into-a-3-dimensional-tarski-space).

Comment: Why is the "right angle" criterion $xo \equiv \dot{y}o$ not $xy \equiv x \dot{y}$ if $o$ denotes the midpoint?

Comment: @Zerox Thank you for your comment. This was a misprint, which I have corrected to $xy\equiv \dot xy$ (which is equivalent to $xy\equiv x\dot y$).

Comment: Are there any interesting models of these Tarski spaces, eg soemthing other than Euclidean and hyperbolic spaces of various dimensions, and their algebraic or constructible subspaces?

Comment: @MattF. I have just realized that in dimension 2 Tarski spaces (i.e., Tarski planes) are exactly Hilbert planes, which were classified by Pejas in 1961. Besides Euclidean and hyperbolic spaces there are their analogs over non-Archimedean ordered fields and infinitesemal convex sets in such analogs. Plus infinitesemal convex sets in the sphere of an Euclidean space over non-Archimedean ordered field. In the latter Tarski spaces the sum of angles of a triangle is larger than $\pi$.

Comment: @MattF. About Hilbert (=Tarski) planes there are two excellent textbooks: https://www.amazon.com/Euclidean-Non-Euclidean-Geometries-Development-History/dp/0716799480 and https://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Euclid-Beyond-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387986502 partially (but only partially) explaining the classification of Pejas.

Comment: @MattF. And I still do not understand whether Pejas' classification of Hilbert planes implies that any Hilbert plane embeds into a higher dimensional Tarski space.

Comment: With that classification, is a coordinatized proof enough? I think you are saying that for every Tarski plane there is a field $K$ and a map $f:X\to K^2$ such that $Bxyz$ iff $f(x),f(y),f(z)$ satisfy a coordinatized Euclidean or hyperbolic or spherical betweenness property, and similarly for $wx \equiv yz$.

Comment: @MattF. As far as I understand what Greenberg writes about the Pehas classification, Pejas indeed embeds a Hilbert plane into a projective plane, so you could be right, but I am not 100% sure because I am quite new to this geometry subject.